# arcpy CopyFeatures_management fails when trying to copy annotation layers

Tags: arcpy, annotation, error-001156

I have a python code (using arcpy) trying to copy data into memory.
the data is an annotation layer (which probably contains special characters and/or chars)

I have the following code:

```
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(u'GIS.annotation', "TestFL")
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("TestFL", u'in_memory\\___tst') # fails
```

the second line fails and throws an exception comnplaining about characters. throws something like:

> ERROR 001156: Failed on input OID 1735, could not write value
>   '\xd7\x90' to output field TEXTSTRING.

Any ideas on why this happens or how to fix this?

Comment: For what it is worth, \x97 is the multiplication symbol and \x90 is a device control string in unicode.

Answer (score 4):

You can not write annotations to the in_memory workspace. See [here](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisengine/arcobjects/esriDataSourcesGDB/InMemoryWorkspaceFactory.htm) and [here](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/modelbuilder/the-in-memory-workspace.htm).

example..

[image]